# Is there a reliable, automatic subtitle downloader for Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, mediaplayer, subtitle

On Ubuntu I use SMPlayer or SubDownloader, which both reliably retrieve subtitles from [opensubtitles.org](http://opensubtitles.org). SMplayer even does this automatically for the file you are currently viewing.

So far I've tried [SolEol](http://eduo.info/soleol), [FileBot](http://filebot.sourceforge.net/), [SubDownloader](http://subdownloader.net/) (which is a bit behind on versions for Mac OS; seems like the API URL for opensubtitles.org changed) and [Undertext](http://code.google.com/p/undertext/). None of them work reliably, some of them not at all.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I was searching for this same answer, and found a great solution.

[Subliminal](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal) will allow you to set up a cron job, (or manually enter from CLI) whole directory trees, and download subtitles. You can also set it up as a post processor for SABNzbd or SickBeard or CouchPotato.

It's working great for me.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in your markup.  For some reason the site won't let me edit it, but try `[Subliminal](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal)` instead of what you have now.

Comment: Is there an easy way to install `subliminal` on OS X? How did / would you do it?

Comment: Sorry, Formatting doesn't seem to be working, I hope you can figure this out.

I'm using periscope now.. There is a very easy way to install it on OSX 
--- sudo /usr/bin/easy_install BeautifulSoap 
--- sudo /usr/bin/easy_install periscope
---
then.. 
--- periscope [*/filename] -l [2 letter language code]
---
You can cron this up to do your media dir, or use it in post processing from SB or CP.

Comment: Periscope seems to have stopped working for me, so I have gone back to subliminal. To install, just download the gir repo (or clone it) and then run sudo "pyton setup.py install" and it will install.

Comment: I am trying to install subliminal with 'python setup.py install'. But get the following error: 'error: Installed distribution six 1.4.1 conflicts with requirement six>=1.5' any idea how to fix this (i do not know python)

Answer (score 5):

I found [Subtitles](http://subtitlesapp.com) recently. It looks nice and clean and seems to work quite well (I had lots of problems with Unicode support in subliminal).

Comment: Although not completely automatic (one have to drag and drop a file into its window), Subtitles is a great option!

Comment: Subtitles is great. However, the last update (I think 2.3) made it non-free.

Comment: Paid solution, next!

Comment: @SergioTapia so what is wrong with a developer creating an awesome tool and wanting some money in return? Do you have any idea how much work goes into even a simple app? Or do you expect everyone to work and create awesome things for you for free? Just continue on if you don't want to pay for something, don't be so negative about it.

Answer (score 5):

I developed a free app to download subtitles on the Mac.

[image: Sub-O-Matic]

You can download it from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/r5craf3ds02xp3t/).

It downloads from OpenSubtitles.

It is not a signed application (I'm not willing to pay Apple two times, as I develop for iPhone and not for Mac), so you have to allow it to run through System Preferences → Security & Privacy.

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation with the product you are promoting in your answer. Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your FREE app. If this is 'self-promotion', then keep up the good work.

Comment: Unfortunately the app does not do anything. There is no interface at all. There isn't even a Quit menu item. I had to force quit it.

Comment: Although drag-n-drop doesn't work, I really appreciate it, works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

I, too, have made a *free* utility for this purpose.

You can grab it fresh here: [Sublime](http://www.salukistudios.com/sublime/).

Answer (score 3):

[Subsmarine](http://cocoawithchurros.com/subsmarine.php) from cocoawithchurros provides a commercial solution.

Comment: Welcome, @joao. We appreciate a link, and a short description of the app. Answers that are just one line of text, or one link, are discouraged. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Probably he was "hardly" trying to promote this commercial software.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [SPlayerX](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splayerx/id414675434?mt=12). It is a media player can auto download subtitles depending on the video you playing.

Comment: Would you buy a software that has a description only in Chinese in Apple Store? About the same with the company website :p

Answer (score 2):

I use [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Subtitles Wizard Plus](http://www.subtitleswizard.com) for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python Script myself to download Subtitles. First I wrote a Python Script to download subtitles using [thesubdb](http://thesubdb.com) API, then I used automator to create a service. Installation is really painless.
Installation instructions and source is on my [GitHub](http://github.com/bk2dcradle/Sub-Downloader) page.

[image: Right Click, Services, Get Subtitles, Done!!]

Comment: Final Result looks like this.. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liR8XFMTtA0&feature=youtu.be)